# Готовые решения для считывания qr-code для iOS

Tags: xcode, qr, ios, objective-c, iphone

Доброго времени суток!
Ищу готовое решение для считывания qr кода камерой iOS-устройства. Ищу в сети, на гитхабе, но обо многих решениях есть отзывы по проблемам в работе. Очень поможете если расскажете с какими решениями работали лично Вы и какие у Вас о них остались впечатления и может рекомендации.
Заранее благодарю за информацию!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Сканируем и распознаем QR-коды из своего iOS-приложения](http://habrahabr.ru/post/130814/) - тут смотрели?

Comment: Так получилось что именно это решение использовал до Вашего коммента и вроде работает неплохо. Спасибо за совет!

Comment: В конце концов использовал http://code.google.com/p/zxing/  В библиотеке ZBarSDK есть недостатки  по сравнению с zxing - очень медленно работает и не может считать код если тот расположен по диагонали к камере.